# How to parse Date object to ISO8601 string in flutter with thinking of timezone?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to call an api with a body that has ISO8601 string in JST timezone.

First, I have an instance of this object:

```
class SearchUser {
  final String   firstName;
  final String   lastName;
  final DateTime birthday;
  ... // constructor
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "firstName" : firstName,
    "lastName"  : lastName,
    "birthday"  : birthday.toLocal().toIso8601String()
  };
}
```

And I encode it to json in this api using `toJson` method written above:

```
class userApi {
  Future<dynamic> searchUser(SearchUser searchUser) async {
    final url = Uri.parse('$baseUrl/user/search');
    try {
      final Map<String, String> headers = {"content-type" : "application/json"};
      final body = jsonEncode(searchUser.toJson());
      final res  = await http.post(url, headers : headers, body : body);
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Then, for example, let's say that I set this for `body`:
`{"birthday":"2023-02-21T00:00:00.000","firstName":"John","lastName":"White"}`.

In my backend, which is written in TypeScript, however, output of `new Date(body.birthday)` is going to be like this:

```
2023-02-20T15:00:00.000Z
```

What should I do for remove this gap?

Comment: What should you do about what?  What do you want?

Comment: You can't avoid thinking of timezones clearly ;)

Comment: @jamesdlin
I set {"birthday":"2023-02-**21**T00:00:00.000",...} for body, but the output was 2023-02-**20**T15:00:00.000Z. How can I localize and remove this gap?

Comment: @Evert
Yes, true. But how can I do so?

Comment: I don't think you should think about timezones at all.. you even called it correctly.. it's a birthDAY .. days don't have timezones. a ISO8601 day does not include a timezone. it would be "2023-02-20". Don't invent some arbitrary time... except of course you really want to submit the point in time of the birth..

Comment: @NaoCOMATSU But 2023-02-21 00:00 JST *is* 2023-02-20 15:00 UTC.  There is no gap.  It's still not clear what you're asking for.  Do you want it to be treated as 2023-02-21 00:00 UTC?

Comment: I have another data that has birthday with JST timezone and I want to compare them if they are same. Isn't there any matter even if I don't align timezone between them?

Comment: Your server stores times in UTC.  If you don't want it to perform time-zone conversion, then only give it UTC times: `birthday.toLocal().copyWith(isUtc: true)`.  Conversely, when you get times from the server, if you want to pretend they're local without performing a time-zone conversion, use `DateTime.parse(s).copyWith(isUtc: false)`.

Comment: @jamesdlin
It seems it works! So, my server stores times in UTC, but the birthday from frontend was in JST? And you parsed it to UTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2023-02-21 00:00 JST *is* 2023-02-20 15:00 UTC. There is no gap; those are two representations of the same moment in time.

Your server seems to store times in UTC.  When your client sends a local time of "2023-02-21 00:00 JST", if you want your server to store "2023-02-21 00:00 UTC" and to not perform any timezone conversions, then your client should send a UTC time in the first place with the year/month/day/etc. values you want.  Dart 2.19 adds a [`copyWith` extension method on `DateTime`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTimeCopyWith.html) that makes that easier:

```dart
birthday.toLocal().copyWith(isUtc: true)
```

Conversely, when you get UTC times from the server, you can treat them as local times without performing a time-zone conversion with:

```dart
DateTime.parse(timestampFromServer).copyWith(isUtc: false)
```