# Two Dart DateTime instances end up with different timezones in Firestore

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Consider these two DateTime instances in Dart (with Flutter).

```
DateTime birthdate = DateTime(
    int.parse(birthdateList[2]), // 1995
    int.parse(birthdateList[0]), // 05
    int.parse(birthdateList[1]), // 17
);

DateTime now = DateTime.now();
```

My timezone is eastern (UTC-5). When saved to Firestore, no other processing is done yet `birthdate` has UTC-4 and `now` has UTC-5. How does that work?

**Edit**
I'm observing these values in the Firebase console which is shown in the following screenshot

[image]

Comment: Probably Daylight Saving Time.  EDT is UTC-4 and EST is UTC-5.  It would help if you provided exact values for the strings you're parsing.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain how you are observing these timezones.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use to reproduce the unexpected results.

Comment: Also, if you care only about the date and not about the time, I'd suggest storing just the date (which would require using some other data type) or storing them as UTC and ignoring the time component when converting to/from local time.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75514206/.

Comment: @jamesdlin I was wondering about EDT vs EST too, not sure how it would get EDT though.

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated the question to show that. let me know if more is needed.

Comment: @Garrett It automatically determines EDT from the date.  May 17 is within the period that the US observes DST.  February 26 is during the period where it's on standard time.

Comment: [Firestore timestamps don't have a timezone encoded in them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714631/firestore-timestamp-fromdate-not-utc).  The console should use whatever your system's timezone is (you can easily test this by changing your TZ and reloading the page - I just did this myself).  The fact that you're seeing two different ones at the same time looks like a bug in the console.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the insight there. On the note of there being a Firebase console bug. Take a look at what jamesdlin said about that date being DST. Maybe the console is correct?

Comment: If you store a "date", like a birthdate, always store it as UTC midnight, and be careful to extract it that way as well.  Dates aren't really a subset of DateTime, so using UTC midnight is about the only way to achieve that.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz In this case, would that mean storing it as a string of Dart's `DateTime.toUtc()` instead of using Firebase's Timestamp type?

Comment: No, firebase is storing a point in time (the offset from the unix epoch) without regard to any timezones.  It doesn't have an external representation until you give it one. So go ahead and store it as a Timestamp type... just be sure you are thinking "midnight UTC" for any conversion to and from the time in Firebase.

Comment: As Randal and myself are saying, there is no timezone encoded in the timestamp. It is just storing an offset from the unix epoch in UTC, like pretty much all basic software systems do.  The console is just being confusing by reporting two different timezones at the same time.  Normally the console will use the same TZ for *all* timestamps, using your local computer's clock configuration, regardless of how they ended up in the database. Try changing your OS's TZ to see what I mean. You should [contact Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to file a bug.

Comment: @DougStevenson I doubt that it is a bug.  Local `DateTime`s should respect the local time zone *for that date*.  If you currently have a calendar entry for, say, January 1, 2023 at 12 PM, you wouldn't expect that entry to suddenly be reported as January 1, 2023 1 PM if you happened to look at it while your local time zone happens to be observing DST.

Comment: @jamesdlin But that's just not the way it works. A point is time (the numbers in the timestamp) is the same for all people on earth and is not impacted by the longitute where they are at.  Timezones are just a way of adjusting the face clock time for that person so that there are mostly common daylight hours for most locations. Daylight savings time just adjusts the face clock daylight hours conditionally throughout the year and does not impact at all the underlying numbers of the timestamp. If you want to store timezone, you'll need another database field (or don't use timestamps at all).

Comment: @DougStevenson You're not understanding.  I'm not saying anything about storing timezones.  Your local system knows its own time zone and knows its own DST rules, and it applies them when converting to and from UTC.  OP tries to write timestamps for the local `DateTime` objects 1997-05-17 00:00 and 2023-02-26 00:00 to Firestore.  These local timestamps get converted to UTC offsets.  Since 1997-05-17 00:00 occurred during DST, the client treats it as EDT and converts it to an offset that corresponds to 1997-05-17 00:04 UTC.

Comment: ... 2023-02-26 00:00 occurred during standard time, so the client treats it as EST and converts it to an offset that corresponds to 2023-02-26 00:05 UTC.  The converse happens when the timestamps are read back and converted from UTC offsets to local times: the client knows that DST rules would be in effect at 1997-05-17 00:04 UTC, so it treats it as EDT when converting it back to a local time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252161/discussion-between-jamesdlin-and-doug-stevenson).

Comment: @jamesdlin That sounds like an explanation you can put into an answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this cleared things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're observing two different time zones reported because your local time zone observes a Daylight Saving Time change across those dates.

> My timezone is eastern (UTC-5). When saved to Firestore, no other processing is done yet `birthdate` has UTC-4 and `now` has UTC-5. How does that work?

*Your* computer knows its own time zone and knows its own DST rules, and it applies them when converting an *unqualified* local time to and from an absolute time.

When you create a local `DateTime` object for 1997-05-17 00:00, there is no time zone explicitly specified, and your computer knows that that local time falls within the period where DST is observed.  It therefore treats it as the absolute time 1997-05-17 00:00 EDT (which is the same as UTC-4).

Likewise, your computer knows that 2023-02-26 falls within standard time and treats it as EST (UTC-5).

It's easy to observe this:

```dart
void main() {
  var date1 = DateTime(1995, 5, 17);
  var date2 = DateTime(2023, 2, 26);

  print(date1);         // Prints: 1995-05-17 00:00:00.000
  print(date2);         // Prints: 2023-02-26 00:00:00.000
  print(date1.toUtc()); // Prints: 1995-05-17 07:00:00.000Z
  print(date2.toUtc()); // Prints: 2023-02-26 08:00:00.000Z

  print(date1.timeZoneName); // Prints: Pacific Daylight Time
  print(date2.timeZoneName); // Prints: Pacific Standard Time
}
```

(The output above is for my timezone, which is PST (UTC-8).) Note that `date1` and `date2` are both already absolute points in time; the conversion from an unqualified local time to an absolute time happened when each `DateTime` object was constructed.

You then write those absolute times to Firestore.  It doesn't matter how Firestore internally stores them or represents them; they're already absolute points in time.  When you read those absolute times back, because your computer knows its own DST rules, it knows to present the 1997-05-17 one as EDT and to present the 2023-02-26 as EST when showing them as local times.

(I contend that it's appropriate and not a bug to show an EDT time while your timezone is currently EST.  If you scheduled "Noon meeting" for 2023-03-12 12:00 EDT, it would be weird and confusing if it were displayed as 2023-03-12 11:00 EST when viewing that event one day prior.  A human viewing that would need to be aware of the DST change to know that the local time would be 12:00 PM when the event actually occurs.)

If your goal is to store just a date, and you don't care about the time, I recommend that you be explicit when creating absolute times so that they are independent of your local time zone rules.  With Dart's standard library, you do that by [constructing UTC `DateTime` objects](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.utc.html); there is no other built-in way to specify an explicit time zone.  Since you don't care about the time, that portion can be ignored (and left as midnight).

Comment: Makes sense, great answer. Thanks for help work through this in the comments too.